# Can't delete row from tableview

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios5, nsdictionary

In my app i can't delete row from tableview. The content of the tableview comes as a web(GET) response and i display it in a tableview, i display some details of it in a second view controller(push when clickcing row at index..) Can someone help please?
Here is some of my codes:(in viewDidLoad)

```
 sharedDa= (BNT_AppDelegate *)([[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]);
    mm= [[sharedDa messagesDict]objectForKey:@"message"];//mm is NSDictionary
```

The `mm` contains a few properties(such as date, message..) and i think i need to delete object at index from Dictionary. How can i handle this situation?

**EDIT-2:**
Here is my JSON object;

```
{
    button = 30;
    message =     (
                {
            date = "2012-03-21 20:13:10";
            message = "message 1";
        },
                {
            date = "2012-03-21 20:13:42";
            message = "asdf nkop jp?l?f";
        },
                {
            date = "2012-03-22 10:06:11";
            message = "test local notification message";
        },
                {
            date = "2012-03-22 10:06:41";
            message = "second test of uilocalnotification";
        },
                {
            date = "2012-03-22 10:08:13";
            message = "third test of notification";
        }
    );
}
```

And here is my initializing code:

```
sharedDa= (BNT_AppDelegate *)([[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]);
//mm is mutableDictionary and the others are mutable array
        mm= [[sharedDa messagesDict]objectForKey:@"message"];
       // NSLog(@"JSON message: %@", [sharedDa messagesDict]);
        buttonVersion= [sharedDa.messagesDict objectForKey:@"button"];
        mySecondArray= [mm valueForKey:@"date"];
        myIDsArray=[mm valueForKey:@"ID"];
```

I parsed my mutable dictionary and initialized different mutable arrays with it, here is exactly my delegate method to delete row;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source


        NSLog(@"Thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

        [self.myIDsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [self.myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [self.mySecondArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [self.buttonVersion removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; }   }
```

My app crashes and in the console i get these three lines:

```
Thread: <NSThread: 0x75719d0>{name = (null), num = 1}
[Switching to process 1472 thread 0x10a03]
(gdb)
```

I know it became a very long question but can anyone give me an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: name your variables a little readable, `mm` looks a little stupid.

Let's say you have three different objects in your dictionary, create three different `NSMutableArray`s to hold these objects and in the implementation of

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

use the method `removeObjectAtIndex:` for all of your arrays.